# How can I suppress error messages of a command?

Tags: linux, bash

How can I suppress error messages for a shell command?

For example, if there are only `jpg` files in a directory, running `ls *.zip` gives an error message:

```
   $ ls *.zip
   ls: cannot access '*.zip': No such file or directory
```

Is there an option to suppress such error messages? I want to use this command in a Bash script, but I want to hide all errors.

Comment: If you are using `ls` to get a list of file names to process, [don't](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: You could use `shopt -s nullglob` so that the glob becomes null. Of course that would work very well with ls, since it would return all files in the directory. It *would* work though if you use something like `for file in *.zip`

Comment: to suppress error message just redirect *stderr* to `/dev/null`, as in `ls *.zip 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @chepner Shellcheck for bash recommends to use ls instead of grep.

Comment: @KalibZen Where? I'm talking about avoiding things like something like `for f in $(ls ...)` or `ls | while read f; do`.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with OP code. he can do `ab=$(ls input.txt/*findMystring*)` and he can loop that `$ab` but using this is not recommended: `ls input.txt | grep 'mystring'` https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2010

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Most Unix commands, including `ls`, will write regular output to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and error messages to [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)), so you can use [Bash redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) to throw away the error messages while leaving the regular output in place:

```
ls *.zip 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. perfect!

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work in zsh (default on macOS) - it will output `zsh: no matches found: *.zip` regardless of where output is piped to. It'll fine in bash, though.

Answer (score 17):

```
$ ls *.zip 2>/dev/null
```

will [redirect](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) any error messages on stderr to /dev/null (i.e. you won't see them)

Note the return value (given by `$?`) will still reflect that an error occurred.

Answer (score 12):

To suppress error messages and also return the exit status *zero*, append `|| true`. For example:

```
$ ls *.zip && echo hello
ls: cannot access *.zip: No such file or directory
$ ls *.zip 2>/dev/null && echo hello
$ ls *.zip 2>/dev/null || true && echo hello
hello

$ touch x.zip
$ ls *.zip 2>/dev/null || true && echo hello
x.zip
hello
```

Comment: If you're piping the output of `ls`, it may be better to prepend `true ||` to the `ls` command?

Comment: @gone No, `true || ls` will first run `true`, be happy with the result and not even think about running `ls`

Answer (score 1):

I attempted ls -R [existing file] and got an immediate error.
ls: cannot access 'existing file': No such file or directory

So, I used the following:

ls -R 2>dev/null | grep -i [existing file]*

ls -R 2>dev/null | grep -i text*

Or, in your case:

ls -R 2>dev/null | grep -i *.zip

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My solution with a raspberry pi3 with buster.

```
ls -R 2>/dev/null | grep -i [existing file]*
```

2>/dev/null is very usefull with Bash script to avoid useless warnings or errors.

Do not forget slash caracter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).